# Searching associations only in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `Author` model and an author `has_many :posts`

When a user searches, I would like the results to only return the Author and **only** once.

**How would I go about doing this in Rails?**

What I have so far (it's returning posts but I would like to return authors only):

```
@posts = Post.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}")
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by only returning the Author once?

Comment: @DamienRoche If aan author has multiple posts, and the search term matches more than one of the authors posts, I would like to still display that only author once

Comment: Are you using `@posts` in your views, or are you looking to just get authors, or extract distinct authors from `@posts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise against assigning anything but posts to the `@posts` variable. Go through `Author` instead. It would be weird to have `@posts` return a bunch of authors.

Try this:

```
@authors = Author.joins(:posts).where("posts.title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}")
```